# JS Performance with lots of dynamic data. innerHTML, outerHTML, or textContent

Tags: javascript, html

after reading a lot of posts here, I've come to the conclusion that **textContent** is faster than **innerHTML** and **outerHTML**; but what happens when I have a lot of data that needs to be replaced?

I have a table with dynamic second columns such as follows. Keep in mind a JS function will show/hide metric or imperial `<span>` when clicked.

When a new variant is selected, data in the second cells will change.

```
  <div class="spec-table" id="SpecTable">
    <table class="table">
      <tr>
        <td>dimension_1_title</td>
        <td><span class="spec-table_metric">dimension_1_metric</span><span class="spec-table_imperial">dimension_1_imperial</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>dimension_2_title</td>
        <td><span class="spec-table_metric">dimension_2_metric</span><span class="spec-table_imperial">dimension_2_imperial</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Other information</td>
        <td><span class="spec-table_metric">Other information metric</span><span class="spec-table_imperial">Other information imperial</span></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
```

Would it make sense if I put the entirety of my HTML table into JS variables for each variant and use `getElementById(#SpecTable).innerHTML` to replace it or use 6 functions to change each `<span>` individually by using `getElementById(#IDs for Spans).textContent`?

I'm confused as I may have 5 variants, which means 30 JS variables to collect and match when needed, whereas only 5 JS variables that contain the whole table.

In addition, is it better or worst if I get rid of the `<div>` and use outerHTML to change the table?

I'm a beginner at JS, and if you have other recommendations, I appreciate your input.

Comment: Let me ask you this: is it slow yet? One method may be faster, but unless you're actually hitting a bottleneck, you may be prematurely optimizing. Favor the extensible and maintainable solution over the fast one unless you are actually seeing a slow down. I can't remember which library it was but it originally tried to do a bunch of DOM api calls and then figured out at some point that it was easier to just replace innerHTML but optimize when they did replacements.

Comment: Also, if its possible, just don't render all the data. If 90% of the data is offscreen, dont render it.

Comment: Thank you, I'm rethinking my method because I have slightly more experience now and have to migrate to a new theme anyways. This change wouldn't take much time in addition to all the other changes I need to do.
The reason they are rendered first is that I use Shopify and store data in metafields. To access the metafields in JS I have to create a for loop and define the variables with variant Id attached to them. My JS functions match the variant IDs and find the variables for the selected variant.
That's the only way I know how to access metafields in JS